# Testing fails because the prop was not rendered yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, use-effect

I'm trying to write a test that searches a rendered Dom element, but it is rendered with useEffect, so the test fails because it's rendered a bit later.
 for example:

```
const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
        setIsTrue(!isTrue);
      }, []);

    <div>
      {isTrue && <div className="test">test</div>}
    </div>
```

when the dom renders the div with the className="test" is not rendered only after useEffect is, but I have a test called:

```
 test("test", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(".test").first().text()).toEqual("test");
  });
```

and it fails because it only sees the first render, how can I change the test so it will see the rendered div post useEffect?

EDIT: 
I tried using act but it still doesn't work

```
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
  import { mount } from "enzyme";
  act(() => {
      component = mount(<App />);
    });
```

Comment: have you tried `wrapper.render().find(".test")` to render it a second time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this problem before, I believe you need to use the `update` method of your mounted wrapper:

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html

So your test would look something like this:

```
test("test", () => {
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find(".test").first().text()).toEqual("test");
});
```